# MPI Receive much slower when called in child thread rather than parent

Tags: c, multithreading, mpi, hpc

In the code below I try to receive an MPI message having two active threads. Passing 0 as command line argument the parent thread will use MPI_Recv and the child will send it. Passing 1 will cause the child to use MPI_Recv and the parent to send. I see huge differences in the times that I get between the 2 case as the size of the message becomes bigger. Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_t _comm_thread;
#define KILO 1024
#define MILLION 1000000
#define START_TIMER(timer) { gettimeofday(&(timer), NULL); }

#define STOP_TIMER(timer) { gettimeofday(&(timer), NULL); }
#define TIME_DIFF(timer1, timer2, total) { \
  long long sec_diff = 0; \
  long long usec_diff = 0; \
  sec_diff = (timer2).tv_sec - (timer1).tv_sec; \
  usec_diff = (timer2).tv_usec - (timer1).tv_usec; \
  (total) += (sec_diff * MILLION) + usec_diff; \
}
short done_flag = 0;
short finished = 0;
int num_messages = 500;
int payload_sizes[] = {1, 2, 4 , 8, 16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2*KILO,4*KILO,8*KILO,16*KILO,32*KILO,64*KILO,128*KILO,256*KILO,512*KILO,KILO*KILO};
// int payload_sizes[] = {KILO*KILO};
int num_payload_sizes = 21;
int loops=0;

void* receive(void* args){

    int my_proc;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_proc);
    long long total;
    struct timeval start, stop;

    if( my_proc==0 ){

        int i;
        char buffer [KILO*KILO];    
        for(i=0;i<num_payload_sizes;++i)
        {
            done_flag = 0;
            total = 0;
            int j;
            START_TIMER(start)
            for(j=0;j<num_messages;++j)
            {
                MPI_Send(buffer,payload_sizes[i],MPI_BYTE,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);      
            }
            STOP_TIMER(stop)
            TIME_DIFF(start,stop,total)
            printf("Payload size: %d : time : %lld usec\n",payload_sizes[i],(total)/num_messages);
        }

    }
    else{

    int cnt=0;
    char* buffer;

    while(1){

        MPI_Status stat;
        int size;
        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat); 
        MPI_Get_count(&stat,MPI_BYTE,&size);
        buffer = (char *)malloc(size);
        MPI_Recv(buffer,size,MPI_BYTE,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);        
        cnt++;
        if(cnt == num_messages){
            loops++;
            cnt =0;
        }
        if(loops == num_payload_sizes){
            free(buffer);
            break;      
        }
        free(buffer);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void * nothing(void *args){

    pthread_exit(0);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int provided;
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Please pass as argument 0 to run the MPI_Recv in parent or 1 to run it in the child\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int choice = atoi(argv[1]);
    MPI_Init_thread( NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED,&provided);
    if( provided!= MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED){
        printf("MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED is not provided\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if( choice == 0){

        pthread_create( &_comm_thread, NULL, nothing, NULL);
        receive(NULL);
    }else if(choice == 1){

        pthread_create( &_comm_thread, NULL, receive, NULL);
    }else{ 
        printf("Must choose 0 or 1\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_join(_comm_thread,NULL);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not a general MPI issue, but a performance issue specific to a given implementation. which library (vendor and version) are you running ?

Comment: The question is unclear.  It would be useful to see some numbers.  There are approximately umpty-thousand questions on timing parallel programs here on SO where fundamental mis-measurements (not obvious in this question) or mis-understandings (not obviously absent in this question) lead to an answer along the lines of *You've mismeasured / misunderstood ...*